# Image prevents flex item from stretching to bottom of screen

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I'm trying to define a two column layout using flexbox where the first column has an image and both columns have different background colors. I'd like both columns to stretch to the bottom of the window.

However, I get a white space at the bottom of the right column whenever I resize the browser window to a low enough height.

Here's an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHvfL.png) of the behavior. In this case I'd like the red column to extend all the way down to bottom of the screen.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? I'd like to prevent stretching the image too much.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  background: lightblue;
  flex: 2;
}

.left img {
  max-width: 650px;
  width: 100%;
}

.right {
  background: lightcoral;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400" />
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>Some content.</p>
    <p>Some content.</p>
    <p>Some content.</p>
    <p>Some content.</p>
    <p>Some content.</p>
    <p>Some content.</p>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `min-height: 100vh;` on the container class, so it does not shrink when window height is smaller than the image height

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height:100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.left {
  background: lightblue;
  flex: 2;
}

.left img {
  max-width: 650px;
  width: 100%;
}

.right {
  background: lightcoral;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400" />
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>Some content.</p>
    <p>Some content.</p>
    <p>Some content.</p>
    <p>Some content.</p>
    <p>Some content.</p>
    <p>Some content.</p>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: If I remove the `height: 100%` attribute on `body` and `height`, then the columns won't take up the full height of the window when it's fully expanded.

Comment: @Tralmot, you need to use viewport units to achieve full height. I edited the code

Comment: Close! But the whitespace is still there if I resize the window height to be shorter than the image.

Comment: @Tralmot i dont undestand whats the desired behavior, do you need to resize image on small window height? do you need that the image hide from bottom?, do you need that the site makes scroll on small window height?

Comment: From another comment I posted:

I'd like the columns to always stretch the full viewport (i.e. both colors stretch to the bottom of the screen). If the window is resized such that the height of the viewport is smaller than the image (and the content scrolls), I'd still like both columns to stretch to the bottom. Right now I get a whitespace on the right column.

Comment: @Tralmot Now i get it, so min-height: 100vh on the .container does the trick, edited again

Answer (score 1):

Removing the set height for body/height takes care of it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  background: lightblue;
  flex: 2;
}

.left img {
  max-width: 650px;
  width: 100%
}

.right {
  background: lightcoral;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400" />
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p>Some content.</p>
    <p>Some content.</p>
    <p>Some content.</p>
    <p>Some content.</p>
    <p>Some content.</p>
    <p>Some content.</p>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I remove the `height: 100%` attribute on `body` and `height`, then the columns won't take up the full height of the window when it's fully expanded.

Comment: So it needs to be the full height of the viewport, but never bigger or smaller? And .right needs to be full height as well?

Comment: I'd like the columns to always stretch the full viewport (i.e. both colors stretch to the bottom of the screen). If the window is resized such that the height of the viewport is smaller than the image (and the content scrolls), I'd still like both columns to stretch the bottom. Right now I get a whitespace on the right column.